# Facebook SDK json file in Application Documents

Tags: ios, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using Facebook SDK in my iOS application. I noticed strange behavior, when my app goes into background Facebook SDK creates file in App Documents folder: com-facebook-sdk-AppEventsPersistedEvents.json

Is there exist any way to avoid saving this file in App Documents folder.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to know this as well. I don't see why it would not save this to the library folder instead. This looks unclean the way it is.

Comment: I have already posted the bug. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/464103863692346/?comment_id=1627053127519298